# camlp4 syntax extension, parser error

Tags: ocaml, camlp4

I created a syntax extension that allow the definition of a type as

```
type.yjson type_name {
  /* type_declaration */
}
```

to be able to build a record value directly from a json file.
The syntax extension insert a module and the function necessary to do so.
Until here, no problem. The syntax extension do exactly what I wanted.

I start having some issue if I want to use "yjson" at some other place in my code (i.e:function parameter).

Here what I tried:

```
EXTEND Gram
str_item:
    [
      [ KEYWORD "type"; KEYWORD "."; "yjson"; tdl_raw = type_declaration ->
```

Here the error I get when I use "yjson" as a function parameter

```
[fun_binding] expected after [ipatt] (in [let_binding])
```

I don't really understand what happen here. It doesn't seems like the rule have been match, so why do I get a parse error ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I do not perfectly understand the P4's mechanism around this, but `[ [ "blahblah" -> ...` makes `blahblah` as a new keyword of the language, so you can no longer use `blahblah` as a function argument.

To see this, try preprocess your pa_*.ml by camlp4of and see how `"blahblah"` is expanded to `Gram.Skeyword "blahblah"`. It seems that this `Skeyword _` is passed to `Structure.using` via `Insert.insert` of P4 and the string is registered as a new keyword.

To keep `yjson` usable as a normal variable, use `id = LIDENT` instead of `"yjson"` in your rule, then check `id`'s content is `"yjson"` or not in your action.

Answer (score 4):

If I can make a slightly off-topic remark, I think it's wrong to design a custom syntax for type-directed code generation, when there already exist two different syntaxes (one for [type_conv](https://bitbucket.org/mmottl/type_conv) and one for deriving), one of which (type-conv) is becoming a *de facto* standard.

```
type foo = {
   ...
} with json
```

If you pick a syntax for this, you *should* use this one unless you have very good reasons not to. In fact, type-conv itself is a helper utility to let you write your own type-directed code generators, so you may as well use type-conv directly for what you're trying to do.

(You probably know about Martin Jambon's [Atdgen](http://mylifelabs.github.io/atdgen-tutorial.html), which made a conscious choice not to use Camlp4; there is ongoing work by Alain Frisch to support annotations directly in the OCaml syntax, but that's not yet ready for consumption.)

Comment: I totally agree. I actually already re-wrote the whole thing with a deriving generator. But this error was bugging me for a while.